# Remove certain string blocks from python string

Tags: python

I have a large array of strings which I need to edit according to some rules. One of these rules is that a string should not have blocks with parenthesis. For example-

```
"(Speaking) (Laughing) Get out of here" # Desired output - "Get out of here"
```

or

```
"(Dancing)Where have you been" # Desired output - "Where have you been"
```

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibly interesting alternative is a simple state machine.  It should be pretty performant too.

```
c = """(Speaking) (Laughing) Get out of here"""

paren_count = 0
out = []

for char in c:
    if char == "(":
        paren_count += 1
        continue
    elif char == ")":
        paren_count -= 1
        continue
    if paren_count == 0:
        out.append(char)

print "".join(out).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?![^()]*\))(?!\s[^a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z ]+)
```

You can use this regex to do what you want.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/12

use it like

```
import re
x="(Speaking) (Laughing) Get out of here"
print re.findall(r"(?![^()]*\))([a-zA-Z ]+)",x)
```

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that this regex won't handle nested parenthesis correctly.

Comment: It fails when string is like "-".

Comment: @gliese581g `-` is a valid input?

Comment: @gliese581g which test case does it fail.it does not accept `-` or `.-`